# lfs fall with custom lfs server App Center

Tags: visual-studio-app-center

I have added a lfs config file `.lfsconfig` to my repo,

```
[lfs]
  url = "https://{xxx}}"
```

At Travis CI, it run as i expected.
But at App Center, Seem it cannot recognise `.lfsconfig`, and use the GitHub lfs url one.

```
2019-07-03T07:22:34.4356490Z ##[section]Starting: Checkout
2019-07-03T07:22:34.4360890Z ==============================================================================
2019-07-03T07:22:34.4361160Z Task         : Get sources
2019-07-03T07:22:34.4361330Z Description  : Get sources from a repository. Supports Git, TfsVC, and SVN repositories.
2019-07-03T07:22:34.4361540Z Version      : 1.0.0
2019-07-03T07:22:34.4361760Z Author       : Microsoft
2019-07-03T07:22:34.4361930Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=798199)
2019-07-03T07:22:34.4362190Z ==============================================================================
2019-07-03T07:22:35.1331900Z Syncing repository: {repo} (ExternalGit)
2019-07-03T07:22:35.3173960Z ##[command]git version
2019-07-03T07:22:35.4055670Z git version 2.21.0
2019-07-03T07:22:35.4360390Z ##[command]git lfs version
2019-07-03T07:22:35.6350960Z git-lfs/2.7.2 (GitHub; darwin amd64; go 1.12.4)
2019-07-03T07:22:35.6734720Z ##[command]git init "/Users/vsts/agent/2.153.2/work/1/s"
2019-07-03T07:22:35.7248590Z Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/vsts/agent/2.153.2/work/1/s/.git/
2019-07-03T07:22:35.7314230Z ##[command]git remote add origin https://github.com/{my}/{repo}.git
2019-07-03T07:22:35.7467200Z ##[command]git config gc.auto 0
2019-07-03T07:22:35.7601000Z ##[command]git config --get-all http.https://github.com/{my}/{repo}.git.extraheader
2019-07-03T07:22:35.7688370Z ##[command]git config --get-all http.proxy
2019-07-03T07:22:35.7800530Z ##[command]git remote set-url origin https://***:***@github.com/{my}/{repo}.git
2019-07-03T07:22:35.7911940Z ##[command]git remote set-url --push origin https://***:***@github.com/{my}/{repo}.git
2019-07-03T07:22:35.8030150Z ##[command]git lfs install --local
2019-07-03T07:22:35.9461390Z Updated git hooks.
2019-07-03T07:22:35.9461770Z Git LFS initialized.
2019-07-03T07:22:35.9506710Z ##[command]git config remote.origin.lfsurl https://***:***@github.com/{my}/{repo}.git/info/lfs
2019-07-03T07:22:35.9588600Z ##[command]git config remote.origin.lfspushurl https://***:***@github.com/{my}/{repo}.git/info/lfs
```

Is there any way i can use set the lfs url at App Center ?

Answer (score 0):

`git config remote.origin.lfsurl` overrides lfsconfig unfortunately.

see https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/man/git-lfs-config.5.ronn#configuration-files

"Settings from Git configuration files override the .lfsconfig file. This allows you to override settings like lfs.url in your local environment without having to modify the .lfsconfig file."